# jQuery reset all Selectboxes excluding the calling one

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a form where a user can select timing intervals. But I only want that the could choose only one option. On selecting a value from a dropdown jQuery should reset the other dropdowns.
HTML (and php but not relevant):

```
<select class="span1" name="repeatminute" id="repeatIntervalTiming" onChange="disableOther(this)">
            <?php for($i=0; $i<61;$i++){ echo "<option>$i</option>"; } ?>
            </select>
            minute(s)</label>
              <label>
            <select class="span1" name="repeathour" id="repeatIntervalTiming" onChange="disableOther(this)">
            <?php for($i=0; $i<25;$i++){ echo "<option>$i</option>"; } ?>
            </select>
             hour(s)</label>
            <label>
            <label>
                 <select class="span1" name="repeatday" id="repeatIntervalTiming" onChange="disableOther(this)">
            <?php for($i=0; $i<32;$i++){ echo "<option>$i</option>"; } ?>
            </select>
            day(s)</label>
            <label>
            <select class="span1" name="repeatmonth" id="repeatIntervalTiming" onChange="disableOther(this)">
            <?php for($i=0; $i<13;$i++){ echo "<option>$i</option>"; } ?>
             </select>
             month(s)</label>
```

Here is my jQuery try:

```
function disableOther(caller){
    $('#repeatIntervalTiming').each(function(index) {
        if ($(this).text() != caller.textContent){
            $(this).val(0);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Start by not giving all the `<select>` the same id.

Comment: id should always be unique! Use class instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a `.not()` method in jQuery which removes element(s) from the set of matched elements.

```
$('select.span1').change(function() {
    $('select.span1').not($(this)).val('');
});
```

Documentation [here](http://api.jquery.com/not/).

PS1: Use unique IDs! I have changed your ID selector to class selector.

PS2: Avoid inline javascript if possible. My example is [unobtrussive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript).

Comment: `val('')` would be better than a number

Comment: You are right, thanks. I have checked with OP's markup.. Updated.

Comment: change `$('#repeatIntervalTiming')` to `$('name^=repeat')` so the duplicate id's can be removed...

Answer (score 1):

I removed your onchange-function and added an event in jQuery instead:

```
$('select').change(function () {
  $('select').not($(this)).val('');
});​​
```

See a working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/4pqdx/

*edit* Noticed I had the wrong jsfiddle-link. New one works!

Answer (score 0):

Firsly you should never have two elements with the same id in the same html document
Add the same class on all select boxes and give them all different ids
Once all ids on your select boxes are different you can target all except the one you're on with something like:

```
function disableOther(callerId){
    $('.selectBoxesClass:not('+caqllerId+')').val(0);
});
```